# How to access elements in the current template in meteor?

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteorite, meteor-helper

I have a template like this,

```
<template name = "foo">
    <p id="loading" >LOADING...</p>
    <p> {{theResult}} </p>
</template>
```

This is how I create foos,

```
 // foos = [a, b, c, d]. With each button click I add a new item to the array
 {{#each foos}}
    {{> foo .}}
 {{/each}}
```

And how a foo works,

```
Template.foo.created = function(){
    var name = Template.currentData();
    api_call(name, function(err, result){
        Session.set(name, result);
    }); 
}  

Template.foo.helpers({
        'theResult': function(){
            var name = Template.currentData();
            if(Session.get(name)) {
                $("#loading").hide();
                return Session.get(name);
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }
    })
```

So my expectation is to when the data came from the api_call, to hide "LOADING..." para, and to show the result in theResult.

The result is showing correctly. My problem is "LOADING..." is only get hidden on the top most foo. Not the other ones.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**
As suggested instead of,

```
$("#loading").hide();
```

I used,

```
Template.instance().$("#loading").hide();
```

This didn't work too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it

Template... if theResult is undefined, the else path will be rendered.

```
<template name="foo">
    {{#with theResult}}<p> {{this}} </p>
    {{else}}<p id="loading" >LOADING...</p>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Javascript... theResult is a simple Session.get call

```
Template.foo.helpers({
    theResult: function(){
        var name = Template.currentData();
        return name && Session.get(name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Meteor templating engine, you can access a template scoped jQuery object that will only return elements within the corresponding template.

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  'someText': function(){
    var template = Template.instance();
    template.$('p').changeSomeattr();
    return Session.get('myPara');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @saimeunt, Actually this doesn't work for me. I have a button, when I click it, it adds a new foo to the page and that foo shows some data after a while and I want to change the color of foo after that. Your solution works exactly great, when I add one, wait till it change color, then add the second one likewise..But when I add them simultaneously only the top on changes the color. What may I have missed or how to solve this? :/

Comment: Can you post more code on your initial question, without placeholders ?

Comment: Edited the code. @saimeunt could you please have a look now? :)